# Why can't I connect gdb to the main function by running a python script

Tags: gdb-python, pwntools

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUszE.jpg)

gdb opens a local file and points to mian function without using a script. I hope this script I wrote will point to main function as well,Another question is does gdb debug using "remote"

Comment: The picture contains not the best description, please improve.

Comment: Today, I ran a script to connect gdb breakpoints again, so strange/(ㄒoㄒ)/~~